# asp validator - determine if age is within range

Tags: asp.net, validation

Using a asp validator, is there a way to verify the date of birth that is entered is within an age range, say 5 and 22 years old?

I currently do a asp:compareValidator and a asp:rangeValidator, but i need to add another level of range validation for current date against the value entered in the textbox to notify that the age is outside the range allowed (5 and 22 years old only)

thanks
tony

Comment: Can you paste the markup for those 2 validators that you have? I'm not sure if you want additional set of validators for the same textbox, or you want to see what's wrong with current validators.

Comment: There really isnt anything wrong with my current validators....  i just need to check the current age to ensure it is within the correct age range.

Comment: Well, then, it's easy to calculate 5th and 22nd birthday relative to the current date, on the server. So, set MinimumValue and MaximumValue to those 2 dates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ASP.NET CustomValidator for this.  In your ASP.NET code, you add the following control:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="ageByDateCheck"
    ControlToValidate="txtDate"
    OnServerValidate="CheckAgeByDate"
    ErrorMessage="You are not between the ages of 5 and 22." />
```

And in your code-behind, you'd have a new method for checking the age.

```
public void CheckAgeByDate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse(args.Value);
    args.IsValid = true; //Replace this with your age check algorithm.
}
```

**EDIT**
If you're looking for client-side validation, you'll have to create some javascript to do your validation and specify it in the control's `ClientValidation` field.  So your ASP.NET control now looks something like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="ageByDateCheck"
    ControlToValidate="txtDate"
    OnServerValidate="CheckAgeByDate"
    ClientValidation="ClientValidate"
    ErrorMessage="You are not between the ages of 5 and 22." />
```

Your probably don't have to have a different name for that, but I tend to keep things separate for code sanity.

For your javascript:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
{
    var date = new Date(arguments.Value); //make sure it's something javascript can parse
    //validate age here
    arguments.IsValid = isValid(date);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any way to accomplish this without a postback?

Comment: javascript: `<form onsubmit="validateForm()"/>`; then script: `function validateForm() { /* get date from txtbox, validate it here, return true/false */}`

Comment: Sorry - using a asp validator

Comment: right on - one variation....   is there a way to set the min and max date in the validation ??   like in the old days when you could do inline variable replacement???

Comment: Not with a CustomValidator.  At it's most basic, the CustomValidator is the validator to use when the built-in ones don't do what you need.  Hence, there are no min nor max parameters to specify in the control.