# Create a custom date range validator that accepts dynamic values

Tags: c#, validationattribute

The existing .Net range attribute validator only accepts static string values. I would like to create a validator that accepts dynamic values. For example I would like the age range to be 16 years to 200. If I input the minimum birthday as 1996-today in a year from now the minimum age is now 17 and will continue to rise year after year.
Is this possible or should I just validate this manually in the view model?
**Edit:** I'm not using asp here, this is a desktop application.

Comment: Please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099143/asp-validator-determine-if-age-is-within-range and also http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Comment: Those will only work in ASP. My application is a desktop app. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a [CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This Attribute is basically just a static method that does the validating and I put the min/max birthdate values in the method. Unfortunately this is the only way I could find to deal with the issue of wanting the dates to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

DONE IT

```
 $("#YourField").data("val-range-max", $("#AFieldThatStoresTheMaxValue").value());
```

});

## AFieldThatStoresTheMaxValue => could be a HiddenFor...